# Pattern for public and internal interfaces on business objects

Tags: c#, interface, public, internal

I would like to design a domain model using internal interfaces
and then create restricted public interfaces (for users of the assembly)

Whilst this is possible in CSharp I keep running into messy code related to parallel interfaces:

```
public interface IAccount { IList<ITran> Transactions { get; } }
internal interface IAccountInternal : IAccount { IList<ITranInternal> Transactions { get; } }
internal class Account : IAccountInternal { }
```

here the implementation of Account gets very messy as there are many collections which need dual interfaces etc.

Furthermore I would like to guarantee that the public interfaces are implemented using the internal interfaces (as opposed to directly accessing the concrete classes)

This must be a common scenario, can anybody recommend a clean approach?

Comment: If Account is internal then users will not be able to use it unless you add some sort of factory.

Comment: why are you determined to make almost everything internal?

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish with this pattern? What _problem_ do you hope to _solve_? How will doing this bring _value_ to your users/customers?

Comment: in my opinion, Interfaces are communication tokens in programming and if there's a internal interface then it is not an interface in essence, it's something else.

Comment: users of the assembly only need a simple interface-based api - I don't want to expose the internal workings to them - I need interfaces on the internal classes to enable testing and modularity

Answer (score 1):

using generic interface covariance in dot net 4.0 I managed to clean things up (note the "out" modifier on the T parameter)

```
public interface IListReadOnly<out T> : IEnumerable<T> {
    int Count { get; }
    T this[int index] { get; }
}//class
```

this lets me return collections of internal objects typed as public objects because:

```
public interface IPublic { }
internal interface IPrivate : IPublic { }
```

now this works:

```
private IListReadOnly<IPrivate> list = ...
public IListReadOnly<IPublic> List { get { return list; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bad idea, that model seems to be very complex.

My first thought is to reduce the need for internal interfaces. If you're using them for the purpose of unit testing, then I'd recommend only testing the external (public) interface, and essentially forgoing the use of internal interfaces altogether.

Other than that, if you can elaborate on the need for the internal domain model it might help others answer your question better.

Comment: the unit tests would be too coarse-grained and I would lose all the benefits of interfaces for the most complex parts of the work - where I need them the most